# PyQt Trigger setModelData on textChanged in Custom Delegate

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a custom model and a custom delegate that uses a qLineEdit. When the editing is finished, I can update the model. The only problem is that I would like to trigger

```
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text())
```

when the lineEdit's textChanged is triggered so that any user entered data will be updated on the spot.

I can intercept the textChanged signal, but how can I get hold of the `model` parameter so I can pass it to `setModelData`? I can access `editor` from the sender and `index` can be stored with the editor.

Or alternatively, is there a signal that I can trigger that would tell the view to to update the model from the editor even though the editor is still open?

Cheers.

Comment: Can't you use `QAbstractItemView.commitData()`? Alternatively, if you have access to the delagate, `QAbstractItemDelegate::commitData()`? If I'm not mistaken the `commitData` method updates the model from the editor without closing it.

Comment: Thanks! That put me on the right track!